# How to align to highest column in next row in loop?

Tags: css

How to align to highest column in the next row of a loop? I would like it to look like in the first image, not the second. Divs are rendered in loop:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <? foreach($a as $b): ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"" >
                $b->foo
            </div>
        <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

First image (undesirable):
[image: first]
Second image (desirable solution):
[image: second]

Comment: This is a side effect of floating, you will need to clear the float on every x-th element (different x for the sm and md breakpoints.)

Comment: Please show what css you have used and create a [mcve] with your rendered html

Comment: Look in to positioning these elements with flex. Putting display:flex on the row will ensure that children on the same level are also the same height as the biggest child in that row.

Comment: @04FS I will aprove your answer when you create it based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side effect of floating, you will need to `clear` the float on every x-th element, with different “x” for the sm and md breakpoints.

The `nth-child` selector helps with that. To not have to select the columns based on any specific col-xy-foo class, I would simply go with the child selector here, `.row > :nth-child(…)`, the row itself made more uniquely selectable by an additional class or id, if necessary.